# Create a fake read only device like file with incrond

Tags: files, cron, devices, uuid

I need to generate UUID with `uuidgen` (not through any function call, but external command, because processes which will read the file cannot call any APIs or external commands directly).

My idea is to create an `incron` job which regenerates content of file on read (`IN_ACCESS` operation).
So that whenever the file, monitored by `incrond` is read, a script overwrites its content with new UUID:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/uuidgen > file_to_be_monitored_and_read
```

My questions:

- Is there another way to create such a device like file?
- What problems can arise if multiple processes try to read from the file in about the same time? Will `incrond` and script be able to regenerate the content quickly enough?

Comment: I think you can use incrond to do something when a file is opened for reading, but us "IN_ACCESS,IN_NO_LOOP" so that it's not called from within itself.  I've experimented with using incron to update a file when it's opened for reading, and found that it reads the last version of the file generated.